# Expression language Not working for TLD

Tags: xml, tld

I have created a `TLD` with expression language enabled 
`<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>` , but still problem is that it doesnt recognise the `EL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside TLD file, under attributes add < rtexprvalue> true < /rtexprvalue>.